# Customer: Null while charging a customer using Connected Account

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I want to charge a customer using a connected account. Here's my flow 
I get `customer: null` in `charge` response and the customer is not charged however the transaction goes through.

I'm creating token on the server-side using Customer ID. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers

```
app.post('/custToken', (req, res) => {
  stripe.tokens
    .create(
      {
        customer: 'cus_CLpvRC6cGQRjpZ'
      },
      {
        stripe_account: 'acct_1BxTzKEVtlEQzJtB'
      }
    )
    .then(function(token) {
      stripe.charges
        .create(
          {
            amount: 1000,
            currency: 'usd',
            source: token.id
          },
          {
            stripe_account: 'acct_1BxTzKEVtlEQzJtB'
          }
        )
        .then(function(charge) {

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected result here, charges made with a token from "shared customers" aren't reflected on the Customer on the Platform and won't contain a reference to this customer.

In the code above you are,

1. Creating a token `tok_xxyyyzzz` from an existing customer, `cus_CLpvRC6cGQRjpZ`, on `acct_1BxTzKEVtlEQzJtB`
2. Creating a charge on `acct_1BxTzKEVtlEQzJtB` with this one-off token `tok_xxyyyzzz`, you've generated.

If you want the Charge on `acct_1BxTzKEVtlEQzJtB` with a Customer, you need to create a token  on `acct_1BxTzKEVtlEQzJtB` from `cus_CLpvRC6cGQRjpZ`, create a customer on `acct_1BxTzKEVtlEQzJtB` with that token, and then create a charge using *that* customer (Note that the customer created on `acct_1BxTzKEVtlEQzJtB` and the customer on your platform are two distinct records).

Comment: Why does it treat shared customer as a different customer? I don't need to create a new customer for new connect/merchant account.

Comment: That's just a limitation of Stripe's model at the moment --- the two customers are considered separate. If you don't want to create a customer on the connected account you can just use the token, but customer will never be populated.